# If a user clicks on an image in google images(from a search) can I force a redirect to the page?

Tags: php, html, meta-tags

If a user clicks on an image in google images(from a search) can I force a redirect to the page?  So, instead of having to click outside the searched image, the searcher / user would automatically land on the page.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be done, Wordpress has a plugin for just this sort of purpose.  Have you tried anything like this in your `<head>` tag?:

```
<script type=”text/javascript”>
<!–
if (parent.frames.length > 0) { parent.location.href = location.href; }
–>
</script>
```

Comment: NICE!!! That worked perfectly!  I removed the <!- ... ->.  That caused a sytax error.  Is there any need for that?  Is that OK with google to do this?  Can you get penalized for implementing this technique?

Comment: Guess there is a way.  Didn't think it was an iframe of the website with the image overlayed.  Guess I should have looked at the source.  Good job AlexC

Comment: Sorry, it was supposed to be double dashes, as in HTML comment. Old habits die hard, but if some older browser can't handle the script, the comment keeps it from erroring

Answer (score 0):

No this is done by google.  They basically have an overlay over your site with the image the user clicked on.  When they click out it redirects to your page then

Comment: Someone told me there was a way to force a redirect with some meta tag or something.  Hmmm... is there any hack or something?  Cause like 80% of my traffic is from images.  Like 60% of those people don't actually click outside the image.  It would be huge if there was a way to force them to land on the page.